# I am getting NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

I am getting this error when I run it at http://localhost/myproject/public/vendor

the following is my routes:

```
Route::get('vendor', array('as'=>'vendorform','uses' => 'VendorController@create'));
Route::post('vendor', array('as'=>'saveVendor','uses' => 'VendorController@store'));
```

This is my create method in VendorController

```
public function create()
    {
        //
        return view('vendor');
    }
```

When I run php artisan route:list the route vendor is not listed

I have tried route:clear in the php artisan but this could not solve the problem.

`vendor.blade.php` is under `/resources/views` directory

Please any help. What's challenging me is that some routes configured in the same way works while others cannot work.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `public` in url you run. You should run `http://localhost/myproject/vendor` url

Comment: Thanks but running http://localhost/myproject/vendor/ lists project directory index instead.